# What does 'chemical hooks' mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean 'addiction'? I can't find the exact definition which fits in with the following context in the English dictionaries.

> If you use heroin for 20 days, by day 21, your body would physically crave the drug ferociously because there are chemical hooks in the drug. That’s what addiction means.
>   <sub>[The Likely Cause of Addiction Has
>   Been Discovered, and It Is Not What
>   You Think](http://renebrenthypnosis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Huf_post_article.pdf)</sub>

Comment: What is a "hook"?

Comment: And why did I think your avatar read oblivionist?

Comment: Only certain chemical compounds found in opioids bind themselves to the opioid receptors found in the human body.  The author is suggesting that the presence of these compounds over a period of time is the cause of addiction.  It is the chemical properties of the opioid compounds that enable them to "hook" onto (or bind to) the receptor.

Comment: I appreciate your clear and easy explanation. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

***[hook](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hook)***

> A curved device used for catching or holding things, especially one
>   attached to a surface for hanging things on. (Cambridge)

***[addiction](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/addiction)***

> The need or strong desire to do or to have something, or a very strong
>   liking for something. (Cambridge)

The key here, is in the sentence you have quoted. The *chemical hooks* are **the cause** of:

> ...your body physically crav[ing] the drug ferociously.

Addiction (per above definition) is:

> The need or strong desire to do or to have something...

Whereas a hook (per above definition) is:

> ...used for catching or holding things...

Chemical hooks is a reference to the way heroin effects the brain (it works chemically), creating *hooks* which *catch and hold* the user to want more of the drug.

The *chemical hooks* are the means by which someone would be caught. Once that someone is *caught* (on the drug) then you could say they have an addiction, as they would have a *strong desire to do or have* (the drug).

How does heroin chemically hook the user? By altering their experience of pain and pleasure as explained by [heroin.net](http://heroin.net/heroin-effects/heroin-effects-sub-page-1/heroin-effects-on-the-brain/):

> The effect heroin has on the brain was not well understood until 1972,
>   when a group of researchers from Johns Hopkins University revealed
>   that the human brain possesses specific protein receptor sites for
>   opiates, including codeine, opium, morphine and even heroin. Not long
>   after these opiate-specific receptors were identified, researchers
>   also discovered that the body produces its own endogenous opioids,
>   including dynorphin, enkephalin and endorphins.
>
> When opioids bind to these opiate-specific receptors within the brain,
>   they are able to decrease the body’s perception of pain and elevate
>   mood by increasing levels of dopamine. When the body is introduced
>   to heroin, the body gets flooded with these opioids, leading to
>   enormously high levels of dopamine.

So, in short, the *chemical hooks* are not synonymous with addiction. The chemical hooks are the means to the end, and the end is addiction.